# XPath support in Xerces-C

Tags: xerces, xerces-c, xpath, c++

I am supporting a legacy C++ application which uses Xerces-C for XML parsing.  I've been spoiled by .Net and am used to using XPath to select nodes from a DOM tree.

Is there any way to get access some limited XPath functionality in Xerces-C?  I'm looking for something like selectNodes("/for/bar/baz").  I could do this manually, but XPath is so nice by comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the xerces faq.

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/faq-other-2.html#faq-9

***Does Xerces-C++ support XPath?*** 
No.Xerces-C++ 2.8.0 and Xerces-C++ 3.0.1 only have partial XPath implementation for the purposes of handling Schema identity constraints. For full XPath support, you can refer Apache Xalan C++ or other Open Source Projects like Pathan.

It's fairly easy to do what you want using xalan however.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working example of XPath evaluation with **Xerces 3.1.2**.

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <ApplicationSettings>hello world</ApplicationSettings>
</root>
```

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMDocument.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMElement.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/TransService.hpp>
#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>

using namespace xercesc;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
  // create the DOM parser
  XercesDOMParser *parser = new XercesDOMParser;
  parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Never);
  parser->parse("sample.xml");
  // get the DOM representation
  DOMDocument *doc = parser->getDocument();
  // get the root element
  DOMElement* root = doc->getDocumentElement();

  // evaluate the xpath
  DOMXPathResult* result=doc->evaluate(
      XMLString::transcode("/root/ApplicationSettings"),
      root,
      NULL,
      DOMXPathResult::ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
      NULL);

  if (result->getNodeValue() == NULL)
  {
    cout << "There is no result for the provided XPath " << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<TranscodeToStr(result->getNodeValue()->getFirstChild()->getNodeValue(),"ascii").str()<<endl;
  }

  XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
  return 0;
}
```

**Compile and run** (assumes standard xerces library installation and C++ file named *xpath.cpp*)

```
g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -L/opt/lib -I/opt/include -DMAIN_TEST xpath.cpp -o xpath -lxerces-c
./xpath
```

**Result**

```
hello world
```

Comment: Try changing the query to something like:

count(//somenode/subnode/[@someattribute='somevalue'])

and it throws an DOMXPathException

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FAQ](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/faq-parse-3.html#faq-2), Xerces-C supports partial XPath 1 implementation:

> The same engine is made available
>   through the DOMDocument::evaluate API
>   to let the user perform simple XPath
>   queries involving DOMElement nodes
>   only, with no predicate testing and
>   allowing the "//" operator only as the
>   initial step.

You use [DOMDocument::evaluate()](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMXPathEvaluator.html#8785175b7f816234978a931a60000039) to evaluate the expression, which then returns a [DOMXPathResult](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMXPathResult.html).

Comment: Has anyone used this functionality?  Has it worked?  If so, for what versions of Xerces-C?

Comment: @AdamTegen Yes, I know it's 6 years later but Xerces is still popular. I provided an example of how to accomplish XPath evaluation with Xerces 3.1.2.