# how to get only the children nodelist using getElementByTagName?

Tags: c++, xml, dom, xml-parsing, xerces

I have this XML File from which I want to extract my message children fields

```
<message name="IOI" >
<field number="23" name="IOIID" type="STRING" required="Y" /> 
<field number="28" name="IOITransType" type="CHAR" required="Y" >
    <value enum="C" description="CANCEL" /> 
    <value enum="N" description="NEW" /> 
    <value enum="R" description="REPLACE" /> 
</field>
<field number="26" name="IOIRefID" type="STRING" required="N" /> 
<component name="SecAltIDGrp" required="N" > 
    <field number="454" name="NoSecurityAltID" type="NUMINGROUP" required="N" >
        <field number="455" name="SecurityAltID" type="STRING" required="N" /> 
        <field number="456" name="SecurityAltIDSource" type="STRING" required="N" /> 
        </field>    
</component>
```

so I used getElementsByTagName() but it gave me all children with their children, so how could I only get my message fields without my fields's fields ??

```
DOMNodeList* fieldsNodeList = MessageElement->getElementsByTagName(xmlStrVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Xerces C++ provides [partial XPath implementation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/faq-parse-3.html#faq-2). And here's an [SO question with more details about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106065/xpath-support-in-xerces-c). With that said, depending on the version of Xerces C++ you're using, you should be able to run simple XPath expressions like `/message/field`.

Another option is to stay with the DOM API and just iterate through the child nodes using `getChildNodes()` available on the [`DOMNode`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-2/classDOMNode.html) looking for `field` elements.

Last but not the least, if you liked the XPath idea but your Xerces C++ version is not up to it, consider stepping out of your "comfort zone" and look at [Xalan C++](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/) or [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). Both should have full [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) support.